# Error when trying to send post request via python /composite/sobjects

Tags: sobject, python

Pretty much title says all, I was able to get the snippet within test = {}
to work within salesforce workbench. Would love some guidance on what I am doing wrong as individual "non-bulk" requests work.

```
test = {
   "allOrNone" : "false",
   "records" : [{
       "attributes" : {"type" : "Sensor_Reading__e"},
       "id__c": "679",
       "power__c": "15.00",
       "temperature__c": "72.6",
       "captureTime__c": "2019-05-20"
    }]
}


headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+str(response.json()['access_token'])
}
response = requests.post('https://na50.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/composite/sobjects', headers=headers,data=test)

print(response.text)
```

Error:

```
[{"message":"Unexpected character ('r' (code 114)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [line:1, column:2]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your Python and error message inline, using the `{}` tool to format your code, rather than posting a screenshot?

Comment: Please include code and error messages as *text* rather than images. The former is searchable and accessible on screen readers, among other things, while the latter is not, making it much more exclusionary.

Comment: fixed! please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the object via `dumps`. As near as I can tell:

```
import json
```

...

```
payload = json.dumps(test)
response = requests.post('https://na50.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/composite/sobjects', headers=headers,data=payload)
```

Check out the [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library for more details.

Comment: I swear to god that did not work for me and now it does, go figure lol. Thanks!

Comment: @scarecrow It happens to the best of us. Glad I was able to help out!